# How to load a part of a page using ajax in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

CONTOLLER:

```
public function index()
{   

            //Get all data from database
    $data['products'] = $this->billing_model->get_all();
            //send all product data to "shopping_view", which fetch from database.      
    $this->load->view('shopping_view', $data);
}

      function give_more_data() 
  {
    if (isset($_POST['category'])) {
      $data['ajax_req'] = TRUE;
      $data['node_list'] = $this->billing_model-get_node_by_type($_POST['category']);
      $this->load->view('shopping_view',$data);
    }
```

VIEW:

```
<?php 
if (!isset($ajax_req)): ?>
<div class="show-veg"><p>View only veg</p></div>
<div class="show-drinks"><p>View only drinks</div>
      <?php endif; ?>
<div id="ajax-content-container">

    <?php foreach ($node_list as $key=>$value): 


                $id = $value['serial'];
                $name = $value['name'];
                $description = $value['description'];
                $price = $value['price'];
                ?>

                <div id='product_div'>  
                    <div id='image_div'>
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url() . $product['picture'] ?>"/>
                    </div>


                  <div id='info_product'>
                        <div id='name'><?php echo $name; ?></div>
                        <div id='desc'>  <?php echo $description; ?></div>
                        <div id='rs'><b>Price</b>:<big style="color: #E00">
                            Ksh <?php echo $price; ?></big></div>
                        <?php

                        // Create form and send values in 'shopping/add' function.
                        echo form_open('shopping/add');
                        echo form_hidden('id', $id);
                        echo form_hidden('name', $name);
                        echo form_hidden('price', $price);
                        ?> </div> 
                    <div id='add_button'>
                        <?php
                        $btn = array(
                            'class' => 'fg-button teal',
                            'value' => 'Add to Bill',
                            'name' => 'action'
                        );

                        // Submit Button.
                        echo form_submit($btn);
                        echo form_close();
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

      <?php endforeach; ?>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  ajax_vegmeals();
  ajax_nonvegmeals();
  ajax_salads();
   ajax_drinks();
});

function ajax_vegmeals() {
  $('.show-veg').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: base_url+"index.php?/shopping/give_more_data",
      async: false,
      type: "POST",
      data: "type=vegmeal",
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(data) {
        $('#ajax-content-container').html(data);
      }
    })
  });

}

function ajax_nonvegmeals() {
  $('.show-nonveg').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: base_url+"index.php?/shopping/give_more_data",
      async: false,
      type: "POST",
      data: "type=nonvegmeal",
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(data) {
        $('#ajax-content-container').fadeIn().html(data);
      }
    })
  });
}

function ajax_salads() {
  $('.show-salads').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: base_url+"index.php?/shopping/give_more_data",
      async: false,
      type: "POST",
      data: "type=salads",
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(data) {
        $('#ajax-content-container').fadeIn().html(data);
      }
    })
  });
}
```

I saw a tutorial on ajax and i wanted to use it to load products on a page based on the category chosen, for example if you choose drinks, the page loads the drinks without loading the page. i tried editing the code but not been successful. im getting an error.

please help?

Comment: instead of `$_POST` you should use `$this->input->post()`. Also, why do you use `$_POST['categories']`, shouldnt it be `$_POST['type']`?

Comment: the $_POST['type'] should be it the if (isset($_POST['category'])) part of the code...right??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do this is to use Codeigniter's views as templates like this:

MODEL:

```
class Billing_model extends CI_Model {

    function get_all() {
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from('products');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }

    function get_node_by_type($type) {
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from('products');
        $this->db->where('type', $type);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }

}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
class Shopping extends CI_Controller {

    function index() {
        $this->load->view('shopping_view');
    }

    function give_more_data() {
        $this->load->model('billing_model');
        $type = $this->input->post('type');
        if ($type === "All") {
            $results = $this->billing_model->get_all();
        } else {
            $results = $this->billing_model->get_node_by_type($type);
        }
        $data['node_list'] = $results;
        $filter_view = $this->load->view('templates/filter_products', $data, TRUE);

        echo json_encode($filter_view);
    }

}
```

VIEW (filter_products):

```
<?php foreach ($node_list as $key => $product) { ?>
    <div id='product_div'>  
        <div id='image_div'>
            <img src="<?= base_url() . $product->picture ?>"/>
        </div>

        <div id='info_product'>
            <div id='name'><?= $product->name ?></div>
            <div id='desc'>  <?= $product->description ?></div>
            <div id='rs'>
                <b>Price</b>:<big style="color: #E00">Ksh <?= $product->price ?></big>
            </div>
            <?php
            echo form_open('shopping/add');
            echo form_hidden('id', $product->id);
            echo form_hidden('name', $product->name);
            echo form_hidden('price', $product->price);
            ?> 
            <div id='add_button'>
                <?php
                $btn = array(
                    'class' => 'fg-button teal',
                    'value' => 'Add to Bill',
                    'name' => 'action'
                );

                echo form_submit($btn);
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        </div> 
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

VIEW (shopping_view):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filters">
    <label><input type="radio" name="type" value="All" checked>All</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="type" value="veg">Veg</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="type" value="drinks">Drinks</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="type" value="meat">Meat</label>
</div>

<div id="ajax-content-container">
</div>

<script>
    function filter(type) {
        var url = "index.php?/shopping/give_more_data";
        var postdata = {type: type};
        $.post(url, postdata, function(data) {
            var results = JSON.parse(data);
            $('#ajax-content-container').html(results);
        });
    }

    filter("All"); //runs at load

    $('#filters input').click(function() {
        var type = $(this).val();
        filter(type);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, i will try it out.

The idea is that i have this shopping_view page with products loaded onto a page and the cart is at the top of the page so when you click the add to cart, the product is placed  on the cart above the page. So initially i wanted to create the product section to be changing according to the category of the products(in my case its food e.g salad, vegmeals, nonveg & drinks). Therefore if u click on nonveg, it shows the meals under that category "non-veg" which is saved under category in the db table products.

Comment: Hey @CodeGodie, i tried the codeigniter view as template and i am getting no result? and for filtering, the row in my database table orders, is known as "category" 
Please help?

PS: im using xamp

Comment: ok, well lets debug.  In your `filter()` in JS, Place a `console.log(data)`  before this line `var results = JSON.parse(data);`. Now open up your broswer's web developer tools, and check the results of the console. You will need to reload the page to see the results come up. Let me know what you get.

Comment: i got this: SyntaxError: Unable to parse JSON string

Comment: did you place the `console.log` right after this `$.post(url, postdata, function(data) {` ?

Comment: maybe i can help you through teamviewer, let me know so i can debug it with you

Comment: yes i did,

okay that isn't showing anymore but this is what i am getting.

im using safari developers tool :
POST http://localhost/project_is/index.php/shopping/give_more_data 500 (Internal Server Error).


    I tried loading the function directly from the browser (http://localhost/project_is/index.php/shopping/give_more_data)
i got "Unable to load the requested file: templates/filter_products.php"

Comment: well you shouldnt be able to call us that function directly like that because it expects the POST parameter. did you create the `templates` folder? it should be like this: `application\views\templates\filter_products.php` Do you want me to help you remotely. It would be easier than here

Comment: It works!! i managed to get it to work! Thanks ALOT for your support!  :)

Comment: awesome! I'm glad i was able to help.

Comment: i do have a few more problems(different area)..how do i get to you remotely?

Comment: teamviewer. download it, then it would give you an id and passcode, ill type those in on my side, and i can connect

Comment: do you have yahoo ? whats your id so i can add you on messenger?

Answer (score 0):

your controller needs to to assign the loaded view to a variable with a third parameter set to `TRUE`, then you can pass this to your ajax results. Like this:

```
$view = $this->load->view('shopping_view',$data, TRUE);
echo $view;
```

UPDATE: Ok, I understand your problem now.. At first, It was confusing trying to understand what you were trying to do, thanks for clearing it up in your updates. The problem is that you're loading a view on top of a view and youre trying to combine technologies the wrong way. You are first parsing an array in PHP and then you want to parse results from AJAX using PHP, this structure will not work. If you want to work with AJAX i would leave the iteration and the parsing in JS. I would do the following:

In your controller, separate the functions like this:

```
function index() {//This will load your HTML, and JS
    $this->load->view('shopping_view');
}

function give_more_data() { //this will return data to AJAX
    $postdata = $this->input->postdata();
    if (isset($postdata['type'])) {
       $results = $this->billing_model->get_node_by_type($postdata['type']);
    } else {
       $results = $this->billing_model->get_all();
    }
    echo json_encode($results);
}
```

Now, in your HTML:

```
<a data-type="veg" class="filter">View only veg</a>
<a data-type="drinks" class="filter">View only drinks</a>
<a data-type="meat" class="filter">View only meat</a>
<div id="ajax-content-container"></div>
```

And your JS:

```
<script>
  function filter(type) {
    $.ajax({
      url: base_url + "index.php?/shopping/give_more_data",
      async: false,
      type: "POST",
      data: "type=" + type,
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(data) {
        var results = JSON.parse(data);
        $.each(results, function(key, value) {
          var list = "<ul>";  //As an example, im creating a list, but you can do as you wish
          list += "<li>" + value.serial + "</li>";
          list += "<li>" + value.name + "</li>";
          list += "<li>" + value.description + "</li>";
          var list = "</ul>";
          $('#ajax-content-container').append(data);
        });
        $('#ajax-content-container').fadeIn();
      }
    });
  }

  filter("all"); //this will be run automatically at load


  $('.filter').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var type = $(this).data("type");
    filter(type);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: If I can contribute to your answer, the `$_POST["categories"]` does not exists it should be `type`. Also, i would have return the view by setting the third parameter as `true`.

Comment: creating a variable first and echo that variable is effectivley no different than using load->view without the variable and the echo

Comment: i still have this error messages

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/shopping_view.php & 

Message: Undefined variable: node_list

Filename: views/shopping_view.php

Comment: is the "VIEW" in your initial question the contents of `views\shopping_vew` ? if not, please provide that so we can see whats the problem

Comment: Yes it is, in fact i have added more of the code of the shopping_view.

1 more thing, i have saved the javascript on the same shopping_view, just informing you

Comment: Again, this is a sample, just to give you a good idea of how you should handle this. Im sure there are other ways as well, but I would do something like this to get live feedback through ajax. Let me know if you understand

Comment: This is more or less the correct way of doing it, you don't want to have an ajax request for every function like your example. 1 query will suffice if you abstract the layers.  Most people use a templating language like mustache to output the html. I would however query EVERYTHING at once, and hide the parts you don't want. This is one round trip opposed to 3/4, this is where performance comes into play.